# Parse JSON devOps API in a loop

Tags: python, json, jsonparser

I have a json file (part of it is below):

```
{
    "count": 12,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "workItemId": 1,
            "rev": 1,
            "fields": {
                "System.Id": {
                    "newValue": 1
                },
                "System.AreaId": {
                    "newValue": 2
                },           
        {
            "id": 2,
            "workItemId": 2,
            "rev": 2,
            "fields": {
                "System.Rev": {
                    "oldValue": 1,
                    "newValue": 2
                },
                "System.State": {
                    "oldValue": "New",
                    "newValue": "Qualification"
                }
            }}}}}
```

I need to retrieve System.State with the following loop:

```
for i in json['value']:
    for item in i['fields']:
        print(i['System.State']['newValue'])
```

Unfortunatelly there is a KeyError 'fields' and I don't know why.

It works only for the first element:

```
json['value'][0]['fields']['System.State']['newValue']
```

Comment: This question *has nothing to do with JSON*. you aren't *parsing json at all*, rather, you are working with the result, a `dict` object, not JSON, which is a text-based serialization format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this question is not about parsing json. Second, while iterating inside `json["value"]["fields"]` such as;

```
for i in json['value']:
    for item in i['fields']: 
        print(i['System.State']['newValue']) # error getting raised in this line
```

There is 4 different dictionaries and only one of them has the ["System.State"] key so when the key is absent, an error is raised.
To overcome that you can just add a simple control statement;

```
for i in json['value']:
    for item in i['fields']: 
        if 'System.State' in i:
            print(i['System.State']['newValue'])
```

Edited:
After inspected the dict i saw a couple missing brackets. json data can be like;

```
{
    "count": 12,
    "value": [
            {
            "id": 1,
            "workItemId": 1,
            "rev": 1,
            "fields": {
                "System.Id": {
                    "newValue": 1
                },
                "System.AreaId": {
                    "newValue": 2
                     },
                 }
            },
            {
            "id": 2,
            "workItemId": 2,
            "rev": 2,
            "fields": {
                "System.Rev": {
                    "oldValue": 1,
                    "newValue": 2
                },
                "System.State": {
                    "oldValue": "New",
                    "newValue": "Qualification"
                }
             }
         }
     ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer but there is the same error "Key error: 'fields'

Comment: I saw couple missing brackets in your json data so edited my answer. This may be your problem. But keep in mind that you will still get key errors due to absent of keys.

Comment: thanks, I posted my solution. Your solution was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My solution :

```
fields=[]
for i in json['value']:
    if 'fields' in i:
      value.append(i['fields'])



for i in fields:
  if 'System.State' in i:
    print(i['System.State']['newValue'])
```